# Deny a request using logic instead of user approval

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

We have a PTO approval process set up, each area is only allowed to have 2 people of in one day. Is there way to deny the request using logic if the requestors area already has reached there limit?

Eaxmple:

Area: Billing

2 people in Billing requested off for 8/18

3rd person attempts to request off for the same day,  once submitted automatically gets denied because the max people that can be off has been met

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you asking about?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Building the workflow and everything through designer

Answer (score 1):

I cant think of any way other than using a second list with all your dates that gets updated each time leave has been approved.  Set a workflow variable to lookup that list for the date specified and return the # of people on leave.  You can then pass this into your logic if > 2 then decline.

Comment: You could have some fun with it create a calendar app for each area to use as the lists to add items into and check against for your logic.  Bi-product is you get leave calendars too